# creating a slide show using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a simple slideshow using jQuery, But when I use this code I have error in line two.

Here is the error:
Missing "use strict" statement

```js
$(function(){
$('.slider img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
$('.slider:first-child').fadeOut(1000).next('img').fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('.slider');},4000);
});
```

```css
.slider{
 float:right;
 width:100%;
 height:245px;
 background:#E8E4E4;
 border:1px solid #7894A6;
}
.slider img{
 float:right;
 width:100%;
 height:245px;
 background:#E8E4E4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
<img src="images/1.jpg"/>
<img src="images/2.jpg"/>
<img src="images/3.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely a linter warning, not an error. Your code probably doesn't break because of a lack of "use strict"
However, to remove that warning, you will need to include "use strict" at the first line of your javascript, or inside of the function declaration. Also, I took the liberty to format your code so its easier to read/understand:

```
$(function(){
  "use strict"
  $('.slider img:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.slider:first-child')
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .next('img')
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo('.slider');
  }, 4000);
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Answer (score 0):

To make a simple slideshow using jQuery (and without spending hours), may I suggest you my [jQuery Slideshow Maker](https://www.slider-maker.com/) (sold on Codecanyon at low price).

You just have to upload package on your server and login to admin panel.

Then you have numerous options to create web sliders, galleries, add navigation, thumbnails, layers & much more.

If you need any help with this I'm always available & do my best to help.